# Fixing styles for MDC-based components after upgrading to Material 15 (Angular)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular15, angular-material-15

Upgrading to Material 15 for an Angular project is causing issues with styling now that they are MDC-based components. I'm trying to understand the best way to map the old styles to new. Does this mean we need to now add more custom CSS classes and more customized and overwritten Material classes?

For example,

`Chips` has undergone a complete rewrite according to the docs - "`mat-chip-listbox` with `mat-chip-option` — this is the closest to the original interaction pattern."

Prior to Material15

```
<mat-chip-list>
   <mat-chip>
      <span>Test1</span>
      <span>abc</span>
      <span>xyz</span>
   <mat-chip>
<mat-chip-list>
```

[image]

After Upgrade

```
<mat-chip-listbox>
   <mat-chip-option>
      <span>Test1</span>
      <span>abc</span>
      <span>xyz</span>
   <mat-chip-option>
<mat-chip-listbox>
```

[image]

After upgrading to 15, there are additional span elements and classes being added for the same code. Since `mat-chip-option` does not have the same styles applied as `mat-chip`, should we overwrite `mdc-evolution-chip__text-label` or `mat-mdc-chip-action-label` as these are the new classes added to the span?

Before upgrade

[image]

After upgrade

[image]

`.mat-mdc-standard-chip:not(.mdc-evolution-chip--disabled)` is overriding custom css class

Comment: Hi @user3344978 have you fixed this issue? if yes, could you please mention how ?